# convert rich html with css classes and background image to PDF

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, html-pdf

I need to convert html which include css classes based on css file(s).The HTML also has images as background (css class that has background-image as property). It uses css3 properties and models (i.e.- flexbox).
I'm just at the begining of my search, but few names came along:
wkhtmltopdf 
Pechkin
itextsharp
phantom.js
HtmlToPDF

I had some experience with iTextSharp but not with a rich html as mentioned.

I'm  looking for a tool that can convert that kind of HTML to a PDF.
Can be done using .net->C# - (prefered) or node.js, but not PHP.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've made some investigation, the most problematic issue was css3 properties (flex box model) which were not converted as it should be to the PDF -see details below.
More than this - when using background-image - I set the background-image property with base64 code of the image as the url (there are online converters png <-> base64).

Below are some of the converters I've investigated:

1. **pdfcrowd** - the best .net api I've found. Worked well with the flexbox. The problem is that it is not for free for long-term.
2. **HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp** - C# converter - seems like not able to parse well the flex-box.
3. **Pechkin** is a .NET Wrapper for wkhtmltopdf DLL (command line tool) - also - couldn't parse flex-box well.
4. **html-pdf** - node.js package that uses phantomjs - worked well for me with the flex-box model with minor changes.

There are few other wrappers for the phantomjs which should work.